# ASP.NET MVC3 Jquery/Ajax Problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

With ASP.NET MVC3 I'm using Jquery/Ajax to post data from a form to a function in my controller.
The problem I am having is that when I put this code into my Index view it works fine, but when I put the same code into my CreatePost view I doesn't work. I can tell its working or not based on the alert and by setting a break point on the funciton in the controller.

My Controller is called BlogController and this is what the function looks like: (its a dummy function for now)

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult CreateEntry(string title, string body)
    {
        return Json(false);
    }
```

The code in my view looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".error").hide();

});

function SubmitEntryPostForm() {
    var blogEntry = {
        'title': $('#EntryTitle').val(),
        'body': $('#EntryBody').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "blog/CreateEntry",
        data: blogEntry,
        success: function () {
            alert("it worked");
        }

    });
    return false;
}

function ValidateCreateEntry() {
    $(".error").hide();
    var title = $("#EntryTitle").val();
    if (title == "") {
        $("#title_error").show();
        $("#EntryTitle").focus();
        return false;
    }
    var body = $("#EntryBody").val();
    if (body == "") {
        $("#body_error").show();
        $("#BodyTitle").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return SubmitEntryPostForm();
}
```

```
<div id="CreateEntry">
<form action="">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="title" id="title_label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="EntryTitle" size="30" />
        <label class="error" for="title" id="title_error">This field is required.</label>
        <br />
        <label for="body" id="body_label">Content</label>
        <input type="text" name="body" id="EntryBody" size="30" />
        <label class="error" for="boby" id="body_error">This field is required.</label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="CreateEntryButton" value="Send" onclick="return ValidateCreateEntry();" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: what does `CreatePost` look like?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? What is the response?

Comment: Index and Create Post are identical in that they both contain the javascript and same form.

Comment: Daniel may have sourced your problem: CreateEntry != CreatePost. Are your routes correct in your Global.asax?

Comment: I found the problem. Rory was right to check the console. I haven't used firebug in a while and was just using the script tab without any success. The problem is the javascript should be calling "CreateEntry" on the CreatePost view not "blog/CreateEntry" The result is Blog/blog/CreateEntry which is wrong.

Comment: The Firebug console is always your best friend when debugging AJAX :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have actions Index and CreateEntry in your BlogController right, and its probably the default controller? If so, when you call CreatePost action, your url in browser is like

> localhost/blog/CreatePost

and when you call Index action, your url in browser is like

> localhost/blog/

(as you don't write /index explicitly). So, in first case, relative ajax URL in javascript code

> url: "blog/CreateEntry"

is posting to

> localhost/blog/blog/CreateEntry/

while the second one is calling to

> localhost/blog/CreateEntry/

and thats why it works. So you need to use absolute URL's in your AJAX calls with help from some function like Url.Content, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute etc. Rule of thumb: **never use relative URL's unless absolutely necessary**.